# How to improve speed of parsing in Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("MY_URL").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.4 Safari/537.36").get(); 

        int i = 1;
        for(Element table : doc.select("tbody")){       

             for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {

                for (Element sale1 : row.select("td.sale_type.bottomline div.inner.pl4")){
                     System.out.print(i + " : " + sale1.text() + " / ");
                }
                for (Element sale2 : row.select("td.sale_type2.bottomline div.inner")){
                     System.out.print(sale2.text() + " / ");
                }
                for (Element date : row.select("td.bottomline div.inner.inner_mark span.mark4")){
                     System.out.print(date.text() + " / ");
                }
                for (Element add : row.select("td.align_l.name div.inner ")){
                     System.out.print(add.text() + " / ");
                }
                for (Element size : row.select("td.num div.inner ")){
                     System.out.print(size.text() + " / ");                 
                }
                for (Element floor : row.select("td.num2 div.inner ")){
                     System.out.print(floor.text()+ " / ");                 
                }
                for (Element price : row.select("td.num.align_r div.inner ")){
                     System.out.print(price.text()+ " / ");                 
                }
                for (Element cont : row.select("td.contact.bottomline div.inner ")){
                     System.out.println(cont.text());   i++;                
                }


             }
        }

    }
```

I'm parsing from some sites by using Jsoup, 
But additionally, I need to visit about 20,000 sites, 
I don't know about this code is design optimization or not 
I didn't test yet, but I'm worried about slow processing...
If slow, I want to improve more good design , 
What I have to modify from this code for better performance?

Comment: Kindly format your code

Comment: Your code looks okay. If you did not even test yet, then I would not worry about speed. Start to worry about it, when you find the processing too slow or if you get errors.

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you should write a simple performance test that emulates as closely as possible the type of behaviour you'll see in production. There is no point optimising code before you see a performance problem, either in production or in a production-like perf test.

Comment: ah... Thanks for all! I saw many kind sources from a lot of sites, but when compared with my code, it looked too simple, bcz of just this reason, I just worried  , then no need format , right? :p

Comment: If you ask about quality of your code, I think you should ask to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ah I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com  ,now I got it, Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PeerNet Code Review is meant for **fully working code** The O.P. states he didn't tested it. If the code is broken, the question will be closed as off-topic. Before going **ANY** further, the O.P. should test it. Then, if it works as expected, he can post on Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few fixes :

```
public static string getTableData(Document doc){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Element table : doc.select("tbody")){       
         int i = 0;
         for (Element row : table.select("tr")) {
            i++;
            for (Element sale1 : row.select("td.sale_type.bottomline div.inner.pl4")){
                 sb.Append(i + " : " + sale1.text() + " / ");
            }
            for (Element sale2 : row.select("td.sale_type2.bottomline div.inner")){
                 sb.Append(sale2.text() + " / ");
            }
            for (Element date : row.select("td.bottomline div.inner.inner_mark span.mark4")){
                 sb.Append(date.text() + " / ");
            }
            for (Element add : row.select("td.align_l.name div.inner ")){
                 sb.Append(add.text() + " / ");
            }
            for (Element size : row.select("td.num div.inner ")){
                 sb.Append(size.text() + " / ");                 
            }
            for (Element floor : row.select("td.num2 div.inner ")){
                 sb.Append(floor.text()+ " / ");                 
            }
            for (Element price : row.select("td.num.align_r div.inner ")){
                 sb.Append(price.text()+ " / ");                 
            }
            for (Element cont : row.select("td.contact.bottomline div.inner ")){
                 sb.Append(cont.text());                   
            }
         }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("MY_URL").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.4 Safari/537.36").get(); 
    string result = getTableData(doc);
    System.out.println(result); 
}
```